# Always save date to today's date in database using jhipster

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I have created one entity in jhipster using jhipster-jdl.jh file which is as shown below:

```
entity EmployeeLeave{
    appliedDate LocalDate required,
    fromDate    LocalDate required,
    toDate  LocalDate required,
    status String
}
```

From these fields i want appliedDate as today's date in database(MySql).
I have tried this from Angular side in jhipster code but none helps well.

Is there any way so that when creating a record for employeeLeave there should be always appliedDate equals to today's date.
Preferably i want solution from Angular side. Other solutions are also welcomed.

Technologies:

Database: Mysql,
Spring-boot,
Angular 4,
Jhipster.

Comment: You can apply a default value at the database table creation

Comment: If you are using `hibernate` you can use `@PrePersist` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your date inside your class :

```
public class EmployeeLeave{
   LocaleDate yourDate = LocaleDate.now();
   //other fields
}
```

So, `appliedDate` will always be today's date. I am using Java 8 but the idea is here.

Comment: Correct. I suggest always passing the optional `ZoneId` rather than relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone. The default can be changed by any thread in any app within that JVM at any moment during runtime, so it is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

LocaleDate.now() is server time. If server is in another time zone than user, may insert incorrect date.
Isn't better to define date in .controller.js like:

```
                        var now = new Date();
                        vm.employeeLeave.appliedDate=now;
                        vm.isSaving = true;
                        EmployeeLeave.update(vm.employeeLeave, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
```

?

Comment: As I am developing the application in jhipster so, jhipster indirectly creates BaseEntity and inherits that into my EmployeeLeave. So, directly binding value to a variable in component violetes some conditions and thus appliedDate cannot be saved directly. Also, I have tried this option before posting this question.